# Graduated labels for d3 map: country names > big city names > small city names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this [d3.js map of Europe](http://smatthewenglish.com/literate-octo-robot/).

[image]

It looks rather naked though. What I would like to do is- make it so that from the start it says perhaps the name of the country, or maybe it's abbreviation, such as `DE` or `IT`.

And then the granularity increases (as you zoom in, if you so choose) more information will be revealed- such as the name of the capital city- and then later just major cities- such as Milan or Frankfurt, etc. then maybe zooming even more will reveal cities such as Bonn or Grenoble

Maybe I could set up 3 thresholds and then populate the map with the new info after each one is reached. I'm not so good at d3.

How could I achieve that?